# Como sumar el pesoTotal

Tags: java, poo

Quiero que se sume al pesoTotal el valor más alto de cada uno de los valores. La idea es   registrar las marcas de los atletas de una competición. He intentado hacerlo de dos maneras y en las dos ocasiones solo se suma el valor más bajo al total. De momento mi código es este:

````
            if(sentadilla3<sentadilla2) {
                sentadillaTotal = sentadillaTotal + sentadilla3;}
                
                else if(sentadilla2<sentadilla1){
                    sentadillaTotal = sentadillaTotal + sentadilla2;
                }
                    else {
                        sentadillaTotal = sentadillaTotal + sentadilla1;
                    }
            if(banca1>0) {
                this.bancaTotal = bancaTotal + banca1;}
            else if(banca2>banca1) {
                this.bancaTotal = bancaTotal + banca2;}
            else if(banca3>banca2) {
                this.bancaTotal = bancaTotal + banca3;}
            
            pesoTotal = sentadillaTotal + bancaTotal;
            
        }```
````

Answer (score -2):

debes hacer uso del conector lógico **&&** (y),por ejemplo sentadilla1 es menor que sentadilla2 **y** sentadilla3 es menor que sentadilla2 por lo tanto sentadilla2 es el mayor

```
if((sentadilla3<sentadilla2)&&(sentadilla1<sentadilla2)) {
                sentadillaTotal = sentadillaTotal + sentadilla2;
            } else if((sentadilla2<sentadilla3)&&(sentadilla1<sentadilla3)){
                    sentadillaTotal = sentadillaTotal + sentadilla3;
            }else {
                        sentadillaTotal = sentadillaTotal + sentadilla1;
                    }

      
        if((banca1<banca3)&&(banca2<banca3)) {
                bancaTotal = bancaTotal + banca3;
            }else if((banca1<banca2)&&(banca3<banca2)) {
                 bancaTotal = bancaTotal + banca2;
            }else {

                bancaTotal = bancaTotal + banca1;
            }
           
            pesoTotal = sentadillaTotal + bancaTotal;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona.